# Can't convert dataframe to Stata using foreign or haven

Tags: r, r-haven

I have a dataframe that I am trying to save as stata .dta file.
I tried both haven and foreign packages but I get the fllowing errors:

```
write_dta(df,"C:/Users/../df.dta")
```

I get an error:

```
Error in write_dta_(data, normalizePath(path, mustWork = FALSE), version = stata_file_format(version),  : Variables of type list not supported yet
```

same with the foreign package:

```
write.dta(df,"C:/Users/../df.dta")
```

or

```
write.dta(data = df,file = "C:/Users/../df.dta")
```

error:

```
Error in write.dta(df, "C:/users/../df.dta") : 
  unknown data type
```

but when I check if the df is indeed a dataframe I get TRUE:

```
is.data.frame(df)
[1] TRUE
```

I thought of using writexl library and saving it as xlsx and then importing it to Stata:

```
write_xlsx(df,"C:/Users/../df.xlsx")
```

but in the resulting excel file, all the count columns (please see the attached image) are empty. so only columns 1 to 4 are filled out in the xlsx file. so I wonder if there's an issue with my count columns.

Since I cannot replicate my data in a simple way, I have attached an image :

[image: in case you need to see my data, here's the image]

Upon suggestion from @user20650 I ran the following code:

```
dput(tc[1:5, 3:6])
```

The following is the result:

```
structure(list(filing_type = c("10-K", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K", 
"10-K/A"), year = c("2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2010"), 
    Alabama_count = list(mktg_10k14.htm = 0L, mktg_10k.htm = 0L, 
        mktg_10k.htm = 0L, mktg_10k.htm = 0L, mktg_10ka.htm = 0L), 
    Alaska_count = list(mktg_10k14.htm = 0L, mktg_10k.htm = 0L, 
        mktg_10k.htm = 0L, mktg_10k.htm = 0L, mktg_10ka.htm = 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

As @Andrew suggested, my count columns are all lists and not data frames.

Comment: Hey jay, looks like you have a datafame with a list-column (there is not native way for stata to handle list-columns so it cannot export a column with that format). If you run `sapply(df, is.list)` or `sapply(df, typeof)` it will help you identify the issue-column(s) so you can fix it / export.

Comment: You are correct Andrew. I followed your advice and turns out all my count elements are lists! So how do I change them to df?

Comment: It all depends on the structure of the list. What does this return? `all(sapply(df, function(x) all(lengths(x) == 1)))` (checking to see if there are any list elements that are empty or longer than 1).

Comment: we really need to see an example of your data, you can do this with `dput(df[1:5, 3:6])` (taking a punt `as.data.frame(lapply(df, unlist))` might be enough)

Comment: Can you see the image that I have uploaded? My data is large and I don't really know how to represent it with a simple example. I ran what Andrew suggested and the first 4 columns returned false and all the rest returned TRUE which means all my count columns are lists. I wrote   df$Alabama_count <- as.data.frame(df$Alabama_count) and it gave me the error Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Alabama_count, value = list(mktg_10k14.htm = 0L,  : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 260661

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I ran the code in your second comment and it returned TRUE. So the length is in fact 1

Comment: @jayjunior; yes I can see the image however we cannot tell the nderlying structure of the data by looking at a screenshot. If you edit your question with the results of `dput(df[1:5, 3:6])` from the previous comment, that should be enough to get an idea of the structure.

Comment: yes I just edited the question with what you mentioned

Comment: Thanks @jayjunior; okay it looks like `tc = as.data.frame(lapply(tc, unlist))` or Andrews solution of just applying to the affected columns should be enough. (ps it is good practice to liberally use `str` to insect the objects you create i.e. `str(tc)` would of picked up this weird nested structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, based on the comments here is a solution (to `unlist` the columns). I also included the checks to ID the list-columns:

```
# Reprodible example set-up
mtcars <- datasets::mtcars

mtcars$mpg <- as.list(mtcars$mpg) # manually adding a list column
haven::write_dta(mtcars, "path.dta") # same error
Error in write_dta_(data, normalizePath(path, mustWork = FALSE), version = stata_file_format(version),  : 
  Variables of type list not supported yet

# ID the list column
sapply(mtcars, is.list) # T/F vector
  mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb 
 TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 

# or
# sapply(mtcars, typeof) # returns column types
```

How to fix it (based on the comments)

```
idx <- sapply(mtcars, is.list) # create an index of your list columns
mtcars[idx] <- lapply(mtcars[idx], unlist) # unlisting the list columns (selected by idx)
    
    
any(sapply(mtcars, is.list)) # are any columns type list
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andrew, this worked and I was able to save the .dta using write.dta.